# angularjs connect dropdown with fileselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've predefined images and I want to make a spinner, where user can select these items; but I want also a file select button for custom images.

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="inputQ.image">
     <!-- show if there is no image -->
     <option disabled value="{{ undefined }}"
            ng-hide="inputQ.image && !isImageFromSpinner(inputQ.image)">
        Nichts ausgewählt
     </option>
     <!-- show if there is a custom image -->
     <option disabled
            ng-show="inputQ.image && !isImageFromSpinner(inputQ.image)"
            value="{{ isImageFromSpinner(inputQ.image) ? undefined : inputQ.image }}">
        Benutzerdefiniertes Bild ausgewählt
     </option>
     <option ng-repeat="res in exerciseRessources.images"
            value="{{res.blob}}" ng-disabled="res.disabled">
        {{res.name}}
     </option>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
<div file-chooser ng-model="inputQ.image" accept="image/*">
  <img class="input" ng-src="{{inputQ.image}}" alt="Beispiel"
      ng-show="inputQ.image">
  <br ng-show="inputQ.image">
  <button class="btn btn-default" file-select>Bild auswählen...
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" file-unselect>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I want to handle the custom image in the select with the second option and the first is for init.

but the function `isImageFromSpinner` returns alternatively true and false.

```
$scope.isImageFromSpinner = function (model) {
    $scope.exerciseRessources.images.forEach(function (img) {
        if (img.blob && img.blob === model) {
            $log.warn(model, true);
            return true;
        }
    });
    $log.warn(model, false);
    return false;
};
```

If the element is in the spinner it should be true otherwise false. Not `true`, `false`, `true`, ...
So it's no wonder, that the select options are not working correctly.

Does somebody know, why I get it alternatively true or false?

Comment: You can't use `hide` on an `<option>` tag. It's not supported cross browser. Definitely won't work in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.isImageFromSpinner = function (model) {
    returnVal = false;
    $scope.exerciseRessources.images.forEach(function (img) {
        if (img.blob && img.blob === model) {
            returnVal = true;
            $log.warn(model, returnVal);
            break;
        }
    });
    return returnVal;
};
```

Comment: really; so easy? and can you explain why? ^^

Comment: your original code returned twice and the second one is always false. What you really wanted to do was to find if there's any match and break out immediately from the loop then return the value. Therefore, I just slightly modified your code to do that. :-)